# How to add Tailwind CSS scroll-smooth class to Next.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I want to add scroll behaviour **smooth** to my Next.js app, and the Tailwind CSS  documentation instructs us to add the utility class in `<html/>`.

```html
    <html class="scroll-smooth ">
      <!-- ... -->
    </html>
```

This file does not contain an `html` tag:

```js
  import Head from "next/head";
  import "@material-tailwind/react/tailwind.css";
  import "../styles/globals.css";
 
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
      return (
        <>
          <Head>
            <link
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
              rel="stylesheet"
            />
          </Head>
    
            <Component {...pageProps} />
    
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default MyApp;
```

How and where can I add the `smooth-scroll` utility class in my project?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest solution, do it from your globals.css file...

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  html {
    @apply scroll-smooth;
  }
}
```

Comment: both answers are correct but I will prefer this answer because this is simple and working

Answer (score 6):

Use a custom `_document.js` and add it there - [Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#:%7E:text=props%2C%20like%20lang%3A-,%3CHtml%20lang%3D%22en%22%3E,-The%20%3CHead%20/%3E%20component) is an explanation of what it does -

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html class="scroll-smooth">
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Comment: ctx.defaultGetInitialProps is not a function. I am getting this error

Comment: your link in the answer is not working

Comment: Fixed the link, hope that works

Comment: done thanks it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

For those who will be using nextjs 13 . You can simply add the class (clasName) in the parent layout file like below :-

```
import '../styles/globals.css'


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html className='scroll-smooth'>
      <head />
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```